# Excell Pivot table not working correctly

Tags: excel, ms-office, pivot-table

Please anyone help to solve this sales report , that i got . It is a complex sales report but it is so much simple to understand . But it is not working with pivot table since it contain blank column . Please see the below screenshot

[image]

Here what i need to get is

(1)How much cancelled , completed order in category1 , category2 with price

(2)How much is the total sales (for that i know first filter data and exclude * then make pivot table )

Please any one help to solve this .

Thank you

Comment: Is the workbook shared with other user?

Comment: Please see this link . You can down load http://www.filedropper.com/sales_2

Answer (score 1):

You may create two more columns, one to count cancelled end another to count completed, you can use something like: =IF(F2="Cancelled";1;0); and then, you create a pivot table for each category.

[image]